# AttributeError: 'Producto' object has no attribute 'tabla'

Tags: setattribute

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

class Producto:
db = 'database/productos.db'
def **init**(self,root):
self.ventana = root
self.ventana.title("App Getor de Productos") # Titulo de la ventana
self.ventana.resizable(1,1) # Activar la rediminsion de la ventana. para desactivarla: (0,0)
self.ventana.wm_iconbitmap('recursos/icon.ico')
# Llamada al metodo get_productos para obtener el listado de productos al inicio de la app
self.get_productos()

```
    # Creacion del contenedor Frame principal
    frame = LabelFrame(self.ventana, text = "Rgistrar un nuevo Producto")
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

    # Label Nombre
    self.etiqueta_nombre = Label(frame, text="Nombre: ") # Etiqueta de texto ubicada en el frame
    self.etiqueta_nombre.grid(row=1, column=0) # Posicionemiento a traves de grid
    # entry Nombre (caja de texto recibira el nombre)
    self.nombre = Entry(frame) # Caja de texto (input de texto) ubicada en el frame
    self.nombre.focus() # Para que el foco del raton vaya a este Entry al inicio
    self.nombre.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #Label Precio
    self.etiqueta_precio = Label(frame, text="Precio: ") # Etiquets de texto ubicada en el frame
    self.etiqueta_precio.grid(row=2, column=0)
    # Entry Precio(caja de texto que recibira el precio)
    self.precio = Entry(frame) # Caja de texto (input de texto) ubicado en el frame
    self.precio.grid(row=2, column=1)

    # Boton Añadir Producto
    # noinspection NonAsciiCharacters
    self.boton_aniadir = ttk.Button(frame, text = "Guardar Producto")
    self.boton_aniadir.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

    # Tabla de Productos
    # Estilo personalizado para la tabla
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri',
    11)) # Se modifica la fuente de la tabla
    style.configure("mystyle.Treefiew.Heading", font=('Calibri', 13, 'bold')) # Se
    # modifica la fuente de las cabdeceras
    style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treetarea', {'sticky':
    'nswe'})]) # Eliminamos los bordes


    # Estructura de la tabla
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(height = 20, columns = 2, style="mystyle.Treeview")
    self.tabla.grid(row = 4, column = 0,  columnspan = 2)
    self.tabla.heading('#0', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER) # Encabezado 0
    self.tabla.heading('#1', text='Precio' , anchor = CENTER) # Encabezado 1




def db_consulta(self, consulta,parametros = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db) as con: # iniciamos una conexion con la
    # base de datos(alias con
        cursor = con.cursor() # Generamos un cursor de la conexion para poder
    # operar en la base de datos
        resultado = cursor.execute(consulta, parametros) # Preparar la consulta
    # SQL (con parametros si los hay
    con.commit() # Ejecutar la consulta SQL preparada anteriormente
    return resultado # Retornar el resultado de la consulta SQL

def get_productos(self):
        # Lo primero, al iniciar la app, vamos a limpiar la tabla por si hubiera
# datos residuales o antiguos
    registros_tabla =self.tabla.get_children() # Obtener todos los datos de la
        # tabla
    for fila in registros_tabla:
        self.tabla.delete(fila)
        # Consulta SQL
    query = 'SELECT * FROM producto ORDER BY nombre DESC'
    registros_db = self.db_consulta(query) # Se hace la llamada al metodo db_consultas
        # Escribir los datos en pantalla
    for fila in registros_db:
        print(fila) # print para verificar por consola los datos
        self.tabla.insert('', 0, text = fila[1], values = fila[2])
```

if **name**=='**main**':
root = Tk() # Instanca de la ventana prencipal
app = Producto(root) # Se envia a la clase dProducto el control sobre la ventana root
root.mainloop()  # Comenzamos el bucle de la aplicacion, es un while True

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: hola buenas tardes. mi problema es que estoy creando una app de escritorio con python de gestor de productos he grabado todo el codigo y he creado la base de datos para los productos pero al intentar ejecutarla me da el si guiente error:  AttributeError: 'Producto' object has no attribute 'tabla'